# How to show subheading in Storybook?

Tags: javascript, storybook, storybook-addon-specifications

I need to show subheadings in the left sidebar as shown in the attached picture.

Storybook version is 5.3.13.

Is there any parameter i need to change in the config file?

[image: Storybook left sidebar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [link](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/options-parameter/#showroots)

For React in your `./storybook/preview.js`add this code.

```
import { addParameters } from '@storybook/react';

addParameters({
  options: {
    /**
     * display the top-level grouping as a "root" in the sidebar
     * @type {Boolean}
     */
    showRoots: true,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for Vue

just add the same path title for the subheadings.

documentation : [link](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/naming-components-and-hierarchy)

example:

```
// Button.stories

import { Button as ButtonComponent } from './Button';

export default {

  title: 'Design System/Atoms/Button',
  component: ButtonComponent,
};

});
```